# How to fetch data for multiple values of a parameter one by one

Tags: birt

I have multiple values for one parameter i want to fetch data for each query for every value of parameter in Birt report. i'm getting data only for one value of parameter not all. m using Scripted data source.Open and fetch methods.Thanks

Open in DataSet

```
 importPackage(Packages.com.abc.test.events);

var TlantNo = params["tlant"].value;
var reqNo = params["Number"].value;

poreEvents = new StdPoreReqEvents();
poreEvents.setReqNo(reqNo);
poreEvents.setTlantNo(TlantNo);
poreEvents.open();
```

fetch

```
var poreRO = poreEvents.fetch();
if (poreRO == null) {
    return false;
} else
    {

        row["REQ_NO"] = poreRO.getReqNo();
        row["REQ_DATE"] = poreRO.getReqDate();

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Which parameter should have multiple values in the scripted dataset above? "Tlant" or "Number"?

Comment: Number. i want to fire query with one parameter then want its fetched data.then other parameter value should process after first value fetched its data

Comment: let me know if i correctly understood. "Number" parameter is multi-valued, when "tlant" is mono-valued. For each value of "Number", you have to run poreEvents.fetch. Finally the dataset should return as many rows as values of "Number" parameter.  Am i correct?

Answer (score 2):

A report parameter with multiple values is an array, we have to iterate on it through the scripted dataset.

In **open** event of the dataset, we only have to initialize a global index:

```
i=0;
```

In **fetch** event, process each iteration with something such the script below. Pay a special attention how we get the value of reqNo:

```
importPackage(Packages.com.abc.test.events);

if (params["Number"].value!=null && i<params["Number"].value.length){
    var TlantNo = params["tlant"].value;
    var reqNo = params["Number"].value[i];   

    //ETC. do here your stuff with porevents, declare poreRO, check if result is null

    row["REQ_NO"] = poreRO.getReqNo();
    row["REQ_DATE"] = poreRO.getReqDate();
    i++;  //Important: increment this even if poreRO is null, otherwise infinite loop
    return true; //should return true even if poreRO was null, to process next rows
}else{
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanx.. :) but it has solved by input/ouput parameters of dataset.

Answer (score 1):

The other approach is to do this problem is by defining a dataset having output column which is the multiple value parameter Fetch that column by IN query of the multiple value parameter then pass that value means(output column value) to the other datasets as a Input/output parameter and give binding to parameter.
It resolved my problem :)

Comment: Could anybody elaborate this solution? I think it woud add to my (anyones) understanding of how data sets work.